# jquery, how to remove button colour after it has been pressed?

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, cgi

```
<button style="background-color:lightblue" id="extractv">
     <b>
       Extract<br>v
     </b>
</button>      
...

$("#extractv").click(function () {
   $("#extractv").removeAttr("style"); 
});
```

After someone clicks on the button, I want to remove the background color on the button. I am not sure why it's not working.

Thanks
Gordon

Comment: Why is there a backslash in front of your `$`?

Comment: Is is safe to assume you have script tags around that js?

Comment: Note: while you've got plenty of answers to your direct question, you might want to consider using classes instead of inline styles and then use the [toggleClass method](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why the code you posted doesn't work but the following will do the trick

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#extractv').click(function() {
       $(this).removeAttr('style');
    }); 

});
```

jsfiddle version: http://jsfiddle.net/UUxHJ/

As others have pointed out though it's better (more future-proof) here to only remove the background-color versus completely taking out the style attribute.

```
$('#extractv').click(function() {
   $(this).css('background-color','');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try using

```
.css('background-color','');
```

Comment: If the intent is to clear the style is there a reason why the `css` function is prefered to `removeAttr('style')`?

Comment: @JaredPar, I think the question comes to whether or not the OP is going to want to add other inline style that they don't want removed in the button click. Quote: *After someone clicks on the button, i want to remove the background color on the button.*

Comment: @JaredPar, The reason is defensive programming, the stated intent is to remove the background color. What if somebody later decides to add some other style that shouldn't be removed on click? Or migrates the style into a css file?

Answer (score 3):

This?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $("#extractv").click(function () {
       $(this).css('background-color', ''); 
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#extractv").css("background-color","");
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is to assign the color to a class, then use jQuery to add and remove the class at will:

```
# CSS
.colorClass {
  background-color: lightblue
}

// js
$('#extractv').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('colorClass');
});
```

This way, you can work with whatever style features you want, without changing any javascript!

Answer (score -2):

```
//BUTTON = the id name of your button
BUTTON.style.backgroundColor = "";
```

Comment: An explanation of the code is helpful. Also, SO allows adding runnable code inside the answer itself. Consider using that.